# How to have a clear elevation effect with a CardView on iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I'm used to the [CardView widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView) on Android.

I'm trying to get something similar programmatically on iOS. I've found some resources like this [one](https://alexdunn.org/2018/03/29/xamarin-tip-ios-cardview/). A simple CardView that derives from UIView.

I think that the interesting part of the code is:

```
Layer.CornerRadius = CornerRadius;
UIBezierPath bezierPath = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(Bounds, CornerRadius);
Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
Layer.ShadowColor = ShadowColor.CGColor;
Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(shadowOffsetWidth, shadowOffsetHeight);
Layer.ShadowOpacity = shadowOpacity;
Layer.ShadowPath = bezierPath.CGPath;
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

This is almost fine but I'd like to see the elevation much clearer on the top and left side of the card, as I have on Android:

[image]

I'm no expert on drawing and or design of UI Interface.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set shadowOffset to zero as shadowOffset represents the location of shadow according to UIView frame .
An offset of (2,2) will put the shadow 2 pixels to the right and 2 pixels down with respect to the element.

```
layer.ShadowOffset = .zero
```